# Bigquery PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%y', '21-Dec-2022') error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am getting an error message when running this in Bigquery.

```
select PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%y', '21-Dec-2022')
```

The message said: Failed to parse input string "21-Dec-2022". I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below instead

```
select PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', '21-Dec-2022')
```

Note `%Y` instead of `%y`